# Django file upload returns None

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to upload the image file using Django. I'm able to get the other form data but not the image file. request.FILES is blank. Below is my code.

**models.py**

```
class Module(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 500)
```

**Forms.py**

```
class ModuleAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length = 50, widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Title'} ))
    description = forms.CharField(max_length = 50, widget = forms.Textarea(attrs = {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Description'} ))
    image = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Module
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'image']
```

**Views.py**

```
form = ModuleAddForm(request.POST, request.FILES or None)

if form.is_valid():
    title = form.cleaned_data['title']
    description = form.cleaned_data['description']
    image = request.FILES['image]
```

**Html**

```
<form class="kt-form" method = "POST" id="kt_form userform" enctype=”multipart/form-data” >{% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-3 col-form-label">Title</label>
    <div class="col-9">
      {{ form.title }}
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-3 col-form-label">Description</label>
    <div class="col-9">
      {{ form.description }}
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-3 col-form-label">Image</label>
    <div class="col-9">
      {{ form.image }}     
    </div>
  </div> 
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-brand">Save</button>
</form>
```

When I print request.FILES it returned blank and also when I tried to get it using Key it returned MultiValueDict error. But when I print request.POST, image was there. But it was of no use because an image wasn't uploaded.

I'm using another model to store the image files of this model (Module) because it can contain multiple images. I've implemented the same logic in my other model and function. It's working there properly but not working here.

I'm using Django 2.2.

Comment: where is your html ?

Comment: run with debugger and try to list the attributes with dir

in this case, add this line to debug

    import pdb;pdb.set_trace()

and dir(vars) to see the properties

Comment: @NishantNawarkhede I've added the HTML

Comment: I think you have missed `action` form attribute.

Comment: you are using ModelForm but there is no image field in your model

Answer (score 0):

Like Arjun said, you have no image field in your model. You can create another ModelForm for your model with the image, and display that in addition to your other form on your webpage.

Take this as an example. A user form and a profile form where the profile has the image.

**Forms.py**

```py
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['email']


class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['image']
```

**views.py**

```py
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f"Your account has been updated")
            return redirect('profile')
```

**jinja**

```
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <fieldset class="form-group">
        <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Profile Info</legend>
        {{ user_form | crispy }}
        {{ profile_form | crispy }}
      </fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Update</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```